# Fiber Bundle of Manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I want to show the following:

Let $E \rightarrow B$ be a fiber bundle with fiber $F$. Show that if $B$ and $F$ are manifolds, then so is $E$.

Solving this problem seems easy enough simply by checking manifold conditions on $E$, since the requirements for a manifold behave nicely with the fiber bundle structure. However, I was wondering if there is a slicker way to prove this, aside from this monotonous definition checking? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By definition each point $x$ in $E$ has to have a neighborhood $U\subset B$ of $p(x)$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is homeomorphic to $U\times F$.